# Power measurement for Nexus S

Tags: android, linux-kernel

I am looking to measure power consumed by an application running on NEXUS S.

I could read the current VOLTAGE value from the path
/sys/class/power_supply/battery/voltage_now

However I also wanted to measure the current value but I could not find a file which displayed current value. As in other phones there is file names current_now or battery_charge

Is there any other way to measure power ? Is there any way that I can compile another kernel/ROM on this phone which can show me the current drawn from the battery ?
If yes. Then which kernel should I compile ?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [PowerTutor](http://ziyang.eecs.umich.edu/projects/powertutor/) by guys at UMich
Here is an article by [IEEE](http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/embedded-systems/making-smartphones-powersmarter) about PowerTutor.

Although not a direct answer, this should assist you in your problem